# Does Azure Redis work over http?

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

Does Azure Redis support transport over http. I am aware of the setting that allows me to choose whether to enable SSL or not. But it seems to me the connection to Azure Redis happens over TCP.

> "Every Redis Cluster node requires two TCP connections open. The normal Redis TCP port used to serve clients, for example 6379, plus the port obtained by adding 10000 to the data port, so 16379 in the example."

I have also posted this question on the Microsoft forum. It can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/25d5cdad-dd4a-4912-85f1-3e8ef9fe5440/azure-redis-connection-protocol?forum=azurecache).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Redis (and Azure's as well) does not use HTTP but rather a text-based protocol called [RESP](http://redis.io/topics/protocol). There are 3rd party servers that let you do that, such as [Lark](https://github.com/voidfiles/lark), [Webdis](http://webd.is/) and [tinywebdis](https://github.com/markuman/tinywebdis).