# Connecting to Azure Redis from proxy server

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to connect to Azure redis cache from inside of corporate network. Could anyone give suggestion how to connnect to Azure redis via Proxy? I am using Jedis and spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-premium-vnet) and the case [Does Azure Redis work over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029584/does-azure-redis-work-over-http), Azure Redis use TCP protocol and does not support HTTP protocol.

So you need to use Socket 4/5 proxy instead of HTTP proxy, then set proxy parameters in the Java app.

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();   
prop.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "IP ADDRESS");  
prop.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "PORT");  
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator("userName", "Password"));
```